# $\log xy+\log x\log y=-1$ and $x+y=2$ then $|x-y|=?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

> If $\log xy+\log x\log y=-1$ and $x+y=2$. What is the value of $|x-y|$
> ?
>
> $1)1.9\qquad\qquad2)1.8\qquad\qquad3)1.7\qquad\qquad4)1.6$

We have

$$\log x+\log y+\log x\log y+1=0$$
$$(1+\log x)(1+\log y)=0$$
Hence $x=y=\frac1{10}$. But it doesn't satisfy $x+y=2$. Am I missing something or the problem is wrong?

Comment: One of them is $1/10$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have missed something, because $(1+\log x)(1+\log y)=0$ implies $x=\frac1{10}$ **or** $y=\frac1{10}$.

If $x=0.1$, then $y=1.9$, and if $y=0.1$, then $x=1.9$. In any case, $|x-y|=1.8$.

Comment: Oh Thanks. My mistake!

Comment: I've added an emphasis on the "or", because that's the most important part of this answer.

Comment: @Anderi Thanks a lot!